# Dark Shadows when using AO with Transparent Materials?

Tags: rendering, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

When rendering this scene in Blender Internal, the wine glass in the scene has a dark shadow collect at the very bottom.

I have shadow transparency on, the shadow from the light turned off with environment lighting on and ambient occlusion on.
The shadow is only there when ambient occlusion is on and it is against the table. Is there a way to make this go away while keeping ambient occlusion on?

[image]

This is an image that has all of the details for the environment and for the glass material

[image]

Comment: Post the link.. someone will add the image for you. You can also post the blend file if you think it might help.

Comment: For your information, I have added to my original answer.

Comment: You say it goes dark when the glass is against the table - is it right against it or leaving a small gap? Is the centre of the glass base raised slightly leaving a gap? Another thing to check is the simplify option in the scene settings, if turned on they can reduce the samples used and AO quality.

Comment: don't include Subsurface Scattering in a glass material, but do add more lights! Light needs to bounce around in the glass to come out again, that's why you need a higher 'depth' setting, go as high as you need. (use border render while testing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several thing that could cause this, including

- **Shadows**

  Make sure that the **table** material has *Receive Transparent* enabled:

  [image]

  With *Receive Transparent* and Without *Receive Transparent*:

  [image]
  [image]

  As you can see form this render with the glass raised, the reason for this is that even if the glass casts a transparent shadow, unless *Receive Transparent* is enabled for the table, solid black shadow is rendered which the glass then refracts:
  [image]
- ***Ambient Occlusion*:**
  Ambient Occlusion would cause this too, as it works by darkening surfaces that are close to other objects. (The closer the darker)
  Then you have the same problem as *Receive Transparent*, with the glass refracting the dark areas.

  *Add* blend mode:

  [image]

  *Multiply* blend mode, with the glass on the table and with it in the air:

  [image]
  [image]

  To make this disappear, you can enable *Indirect Lighting* in *Properties > World*
  [image][image]
  However, this can get your rendertimes rather insane, (Just for this low resolution render it took 2:27.26)

And as already mentioned by SteveW:

- ***Depth***
  The Depth setting from one to four:
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]
  And at a value of 20 :
  [image]

## Cycles

Probably the best way to do this is use Cycles, as you need [caustics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caustic_%28optics%29) to get light to properly illuminate after being refracted through the glass.

(quick example:)
[image]

Comment: Thank you, adding the indirect lighting worked, injunction with the settings that SteveW suggested, the shadow was reduced with 1-2 sampling passes. With the settings that I originally had, it took five passes to achieve the same result

Comment: Cycles might be good - but it's a shame about the graininess!

Comment: @SteveW Quite.. (though this was only 100 samples, with less light then really ought be :P)
And there is always Lux and YafaRay as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Raytrace Transparency then this problem could be due to the Depth setting:

[image]

The default Depth of 2 is often not enough to give you all of the possible light inter-refractions, resulting in empty 'holes'.

Failing that, try this: In the Transparency panel set 'Alpha' to 0.1, 'Fresnel' to 2.0 and 'Blend' to 1.5 (You might need to juggle with these a bit).
With Alpha set to 0.0 (as in your settings) the shadow areas are very dark and dense, and Fresnel has no value to work on.
Also, for this 'glass' material I don't think you need Mirror, Subsurface Scattering or Receive Transparent to be on.

Comment: I have the depth up to 8 on both transparency and reflection, does it need to be higher than that?

Comment: @Josh OK, so this answer probably doesn't apply. Maybe you could add those details to your question.

Comment: I added all of the details of the material to the question. Apologies for any inconvenience I may have caused.

Comment: @Josh No problem, I've added your pictures to your question.

Comment: @SteveW I think Mirror is necessary if you want any reflections like most glass does in real life, though it will probably look glassy enough without them.

Comment: @gandalf3, you're right :) When I was experimenting, I had the Mirror 'Reflectivity' set to 0.1 (as in Josh's settings) and saw no difference with, or without Mirror. Now I realise that 'Reflectivity' must be cranked up, a lot, to show the reflections.