# How to add transparency to a group of objects

Tags: rendering, texturing, groups

I would like to make a group of objects semi-transparent. I could not find a straight forward answer and the ones related include menus I cannot find in my Blender. I am working with Blender 2.69.

Comment: You want to add a transparent texture to a group of objects?

Comment: I just want to make the objects look semi-transparent when I render them. I do not have any preference on how to achieve this.

Comment: You may want to stipulate how you want this semi-transparency to look (perhaps with an image). The time-consuming route would be to involve transparency in your material (how to do so varies with your choice in renderer). A faster way may be to put all of the objects on a single render layer and manage transparency from the node compositor.

Comment: Cycles or Blender internal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Blender internal:**

You can add a material with the transparency option enabled:[image]

**Cycles:**

For cycles it's a bit different:

[image]

**Assign material to your objects**

After that you can assign manualy your material to your object one by one, or you can select all the object that you want to assign the material and select at last the object wich has already the transparent material. Then do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> and select Material. All your selected objects have now the transparent material.

Comment: The objects already have materials. Is there any way this new material can be applied over the existent materials?

Comment: You don't have to add a new material you just have to : in Blender internal to check the transparency option and set the alpha under 1, in cycles set the surface option to Transparency BSDF. I've updated the picture in my answer.

Comment: Is there any way I can do that to several materials at the same time? The group is formed by several objects with a number of materials. PS: I'm not working with cycles.

Comment: The only way is to check the transparency of your objects one by one. But of course you can script it.

Comment: Thanks. It definitely works... One last question: transparent objects are still casting shadows. Is there any way to correct this?

Comment: Found it: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1906/dark-shadows-when-using-ao-with-transparent-materials